# Postgresql, JSONB, how to query a joined string from an array of objects

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I've a JSONB inside a PostgreSQL table with this structure (more or less)

```json
{
  "obj1": {
    "obj2": {
      "obj3": [
        {
          "obj4": {
            "obj": "A"
          }
        },
        {
          "obj4": {
            "obj": "B"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Then my obj3 is an array of objects and I wanna the obj inside obj4 separated by comma.

Thus what I really need is something like:

```
1 | A,B
2 | C,D
3 | NULL
```

I'm using PostgreSql 14. Any help is going to be appreciate.

and I've got this

```
SELECT t.id,
       jsonb_path_query(t.b,
                        '$."obj1"."obj2"."obj3"[*]."obj4"."obj"' ::jsonpath) AS obj5
  FROM (VALUES(1,
               '{"obj1":{"obj2":{"obj3":[{"obj4":{"obj":"A"}},{"obj4":{"obj":"B"}}]}}}'
               ::jsonb), (2,
         '{"obj1":{"obj2":{"obj3":[{"obj4":{"obj":"C"}},{"obj4":{"obj":"D"}}]}}}'
         ::jsonb), (3, '{}' ::jsonb)) t(id, b);
```

[image]

```
But the json_path_query multiply the rows and remove not found results as well...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to group the resulting rows by `t.id` so that to group A & B, and C & D on the same row while using the `string_agg` function to group them in the same resulting column with ',' as separator.

But to do so, you need first to switch the `jsonb_path_query` function from the `SELECT` clause to the `FROM` clause while introducing a `LEFT JOIN` so that to keep the rows with no output from the `jsonb_path_query` function.

The solution is :

```
select t.id, string_agg(obj5->>'obj', ',') AS result
from (
    values (1, '{"obj1":{"obj2":{"obj3":[{"obj4":{"obj":"A"}},{"obj4":{"obj":"B"}}]}}}'::jsonb), 
    (2, '{"obj1":{"obj2":{"obj3":[{"obj4":{"obj":"C"}},{"obj4":{"obj":"D"}}]}}}'::jsonb), 
    (3, '{}'::jsonb)
) t(id, b)
left join lateral jsonb_path_query(t.b, '$.obj1.obj2.obj3[*].obj4') as obj5
  on TRUE
group by t.id;
```

see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/TjZNX0om)

Answer (score 0):

Inside-out: climb the object tree, flatten the array and then select/aggregate. [DB fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xgweJtYRMh5AoRFbwm3pV9/0)

```sql
select id, (
    select string_agg(j->'obj4'->>'obj', ',')
    from jsonb_array_elements(b->'obj1'->'obj2'->'obj3') as j
  ) as objlist
from the_table;
```

| id | objlist |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A,B |
| 2 | C,D |
| 3 |  |

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of clarity/reuse, I'd create a function to convert the jsonb array to a Postgres array.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION jsonb_text_array(jsonb)
                   RETURNS text[]
                  LANGUAGE sql
                  PARALLEL SAFE
                 LEAKPROOF
                    STRICT
                        AS $$
  SELECT array_agg(t)
    FROM jsonb_array_elements_text($1) x(t)
  ;
$$;
```

Then this query should return what you want.

```
SELECT t.id
     , jsonb_text_array(jsonb_path_query_array(t.b, '$.obj1.obj2.obj3.obj4.obj')) AS obj5
  FROM ( VALUES
         (1, '{"obj1":{"obj2":{"obj3":[{"obj4":{"obj":"A"}},{"obj4":{"obj":"B"}}]}}}'::jsonb)
       , (2, '{"obj1":{"obj2":{"obj3":[{"obj4":{"obj":"C"}},{"obj4":{"obj":"D"}}]}}}'::jsonb)
       , (3, '{}'::jsonb)
       ) t(id, b);
```

If you really want a string returned instead of an array, change the function to return `text` instead of `text[]` and use `string_agg(t, ',')` instead of `array_agg(t)`.